# Jquery Validator add labels with every valid() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

i have some issues with jQuery Validator plugin.

After making it work with Scriptaculous I decided to get rid of it.

But I still have problems.

Every time I click the submit button a new label error is added to the html.

this is all the td tag,

```
<td align="left" colspan="2">
<input class="clase_campo" onfocus="this.className='clase_campo_en_foco';" onblur="this.className='clase_campo';" id="CampoDatos" name="CampoDatos" type="text" value="" size="20" maxlength="6" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true"><label for="CampoDatos" class="error">Debe ingresar un dato</label>
</td>
```

the I click on Submit again:

```
<td align="left" colspan="2">
                        <input class="clase_campo error" onfocus="this.className='clase_campo_en_foco';" onblur="this.className='clase_campo';" id="CampoDatos" name="CampoDatos" type="text" value="" size="20" maxlength="6" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true"><label for="CampoDatos" class="error">Debe ingresar un dato</label><label for="CampoDatos" class="error">Debe ingresar un dato</label>
            </td>
```

and I get another LABEL tag.

Another problem is that onfocus() or lostfocus() is not cleaning those new label tags, every time I enter some chars in the field where is supposed to be required, the error don't clear.

the behavior is diferent from the samples.

Maybe I should eliminate *onblur* and *onfocus* attributes from the input tag.

Best Regards.

this is my input button

```
<input id="BotonAceptar" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" type="button" name="BotonAceptar" value="Aceptar" title="" onclick="this.disabled=true; /*formAgregarValor.CampoAccformAgregarValor.value='SUBMIT';formAgregarValor.submit();*/" onmouseout="this.style.fontWeight='normal';" onmouseover="this.style.fontWeight='bold';" style="font-weight: bold;">
```

this is my validation routine:

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
    $('#BotonAceptar').click(function() {
        if ( $("#CampoDatos").valid() && 
             $("#CampoImporte").valid() ) {
             formAgregarValor.CampoAccformAgregarValor.value='SUBMIT';
             formAgregarValor.submit();
        };
        this.disabled=false;
    });

   $("#formAgregarValor").validate({
            rules: {
                CampoDatos: "required",
                'CampoImporte': {
                    required: true,
                    number: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                CampoDatos: {
                    required: "Debe ingresar un dato"
                },
                CampoImporte: "Debe ingresar un numero"
            }
    });
 });
```

Comment: Your code is a mess (you're actually breaking the default behavior) and I don't understand the actual question. You do not need any inline handlers when using jQuery. And you don't need any jQuery handlers when using the Validate plugin because those functions are already built in. Please explain more clearly what you want to happen that is different than the default behavior of the plugin.  Also show enough code for a complete example (where is the HTML markup?). I already pointed you to this link in my comment on your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Quote OP**:

> *"Every time I click the submit button a new label error is added to the html... Another problem is that `onfocus()` or `lostfocus()` is not cleaning those new label tags, every time I enter some chars in the field where is supposed to be required, the error don't clear."*

I am not sure what you're trying to do with all of those inline handlers and your question is very unclear.  By default, there is no duplication of the error labels and they automatically toggle when the data in the fields becomes valid/invalid.

If you just want the default functionality of the plugin, and you never explained how it should behave any differently, I think you're trying too hard.  (Your code is redundant, overly complex and it's breaking the normal behavior)

Go back to the basics:

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/nK6f3/**

I have no inline JavaScript in my demo and I've only one `click` handler.  You only need the `click` handler simply because you're not using a real `submit` button.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#BotonAceptar').on('click', function(e) { // capture the <button> click
        e.preventDefault();              // stop any default <button> action
        $("#FormAgregarValor").submit(); // submit form (automatically validates)
    });

    $("#FormAgregarValor").validate({  // initializes the plugin on your form
        rules: {
            CampoDatos: "required",
            CampoImporte: {
                required: true,
                number: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            CampoDatos: {
                required: "Debe ingresar un dato"
            },
            CampoImporte: "Debe ingresar un numero"
        }
    });

});
```

As you can see, the HTML is pretty basic:

```
<form id="FormAgregarValor">
    <input name="CampoDatos" type="text" />
    <input name="CampoImporte" type="text" />
    <input id="BotonAceptar" type="button" value="Aceptar" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Sparky, as an poor excuse I have to tell you two things, one; I'm adding Jquery to an allready developed app, two; i'm quite new to jQuery, this is my second app where I want to use. In the app the other programmer use a lot of inline handlers, i'm quite sure this is what is part of the problem, thanks again for your clarification.

Comment: @Nicolas400, please accept my answer if this solved your problem.

Comment: Hi Sparky, no luck, I think I recreate the behavior, [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Nicolas400/wn9vr/6/). now I can't submit the form.

Comment: @Nicolas400, in [your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nicolas400/wn9vr/6/), 1)  you forgot to include jQuery and 2) you spelled `formAgregarValor` incorrectly in one of your two selectors.  (It's case-sensitive).  Try this:  http://jsfiddle.net/wn9vr/8/